# How to get a union of all the literal values of a given object key in an array of objects?

Tags: typescript

Say I have this array of objects, as static data (it will never change at runtime):

```
const things = [
  { id: 'some-id-1', value: 3 },
  { id: 'some-id-2', value: 7 },
  { id: 'some-id-3', value: 7 },
]
```

I want a type like this:

```
type ThingId = 'some-id-1' | 'some-id-2' | 'some-id-3'
```

Is there a way to **infer** `ThingId` from the array of objects?

Why I want to be able to do this: so I can create functions like `doSomethingWithThing(thingId: ThingId)`, with TypeScript enforcing that it can only be called with a valid `ThingId`, rather than with any `string`.

Comment: It's not really a nice practice to generate types out of javascript object. A better flow would be to first declare the type `ThingId` and then construct the array `things` as `{ id: ThingId, value:number }[]`. This way you are move aware of types errors.

Comment: @johannchopin one downside with that approach is that it doesn't guarantee that there is an entry in the array for every `ThingId`.  So you cannot be sure that `things.find( thing => thing.id === someId)` will always return a result.  With basing the `ThingId` off the array it is guaranteed that every value of `ThingId` will be found.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`as const`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) in order for typescript to see the ids as their literal values instead of `string`.

```js
const things = [
  { id: 'some-id-1', value: 3 },
  { id: 'some-id-2', value: 7 },
] as const;

type Result = (typeof things)[number]['id']
```

Does it work for you?
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFAWBLMBzCMC8MDaBYAUDDAN4yIAmAXDAOQQgC2ApgLQUsCMNANDAG4BDADYBXJtQDMMAL7cCRUhWp1GrdgCYe-YWOoB2GXPwBdGAPShIUANwECUAJ4AHJjABKTCCKGwsACkcXEAAzOCRUCABKbDARBgAjJgAnY2waChpjIA)

Comment: Thanks @Linda Paiste, I'm bad at explanations

Comment: But your code is good :)  It's definitely the correct answer for this question.